# How to add meta tags in angular 4 using dynamic generating values from json

Tags: json, angular

I'm getting the values `({{data.username}})` in the html's..

How to include in the meta Tags?
I need the same values `{{data.username}}` inside the content.

```js
this.meta.addTag({ name: 'name', content: '' });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
this.meta.addTag({ name: 'name', content: this.data.username });
```

Comment: I'm not getting the values inside the constructor.. value is undefined..